# Is there a smart way of securing this window open against the wind?

Tags: windows, window-frame

The windows that we have in our apartment have an internal restrictor that prevents them from opening too far. However, it doesn't do anything to hold the window open against the wind, which often bangs them shut. Is anyone aware of a device or hack that I can add to keep the window in an open position?

**Additional background:**

The windows are insulated, and have heavy metal frames. They open inwards, both at the top and on the right side. Below is a photo of the restrictor, which sits inside the window frame at the bottom:

[image]

The window frame itself is quite large, approx 1.3m by 1m. The restrictor is attached via a light spring.

I don't know the brand of the windows, but the metal "plates" that you can see in the left of the image say "Maco". The window frame has no visible branding, but there is a door in the apartment in a similar style that has "Reynaers" written on the handle.

Inserting an object (e.g. rolled up cardboard) is a workaround, but is imperfect as the wind tends to move the window ever so slightly back and forth, and dislodges the cardboard after a few minutes.

Comment: I can't get a sense of how that restrictor connects or operates from this photo. Please provide another with it engaged and the window open. I'd like to provide a more specific solution, if I can.

Comment: Try jamming a rubber doorstop in?  If the window waggles, the rubber should absorb the oscillations instead of oscillating loose like rigid object.  But yes, a photo showing how that latch works would help us narrow down a more specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly more of a life-hack than anything else.
To keep my own tilt & turns open in tilt mode, I use an old vacuum cleaner crevice tool, similar to this.

[image]

It can't fall through because the rear is too big to fit through, yet the front of the nozzle just jams nicely into the gap - even more fortunately right above where one of the window fasteners is, meaning it can't be jammed in too hard. Insert higher up where it goes in more easily, then slide down to hit the catch.

It's honestly just the perfect coincidence.

[image]

Comment: Like this, so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting an object is a pretty decent workaround. You just have to flare the top of the object so it can't fall out through vibration.

Cardboard is easy to flare at the top. Some tape can hold the top flare in place.

Be sure whatever you use will flutter gently to the ground instead of dropping like a rock: that looks like  rather a distance up in the picture. Wouldn't want to kill someone.

It could also be possible that the window fastening is broken, and the window is not supposed to blow shut. Try asking the landlord or building maintenance.